# Use XML Node Value as Node name and as attribute name

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

im quite new to XML and XLST. I got an Open Office XML file that I transformed with XLST.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ooo_calc_export scriptVersion="2.2.0" scriptUpdate="2010-12-19" scriptURL="http://www.digitalimprint.com/misc/oooexport/" scriptAuthor="vjl">
   <ooo_sheet num="1" name="Blatt1">
      <ooo_row><Artikelnummer>C12-34567</Artikelnummer><ArttikelnummerAlt/><Details>AAA AAA AAA AAA</Details><Abmessungen/><Bildpfad>file:///cmyk/C12-34567.PSD</Bildpfad><EK>1234,-</EK><VK>3456,-</VK>
        </ooo_row>
      <ooo_row><Artikelnummer>C23-45678</Artikelnummer><ArttikelnummerAlt/><Details>BaB BaB BBB BBB</Details><Abmessungen/><Bildpfad>file:///cmyk/cmyk/C23-45678.PSD</Bildpfad><EK>2345,-</EK><VK>4567,-</VK>
        </ooo_row>
      <ooo_row><Artikelnummer>C34-56789</Artikelnummer><ArttikelnummerAlt/><Details>CaC CaC CaC CaC uli</Details><Abmessungen/><Bildpfad>file:///cmyk/cmyk/C34-56789.PSD</Bildpfad><EK>3456,-</EK><VK>5678,-</VK>
        </ooo_row>
   </ooo_sheet>
</ooo_calc_export>
```

I transformed the XML with the following XLST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method = "xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="ooo_sheet">
<xsl:element name="Import">
<xsl:for-each select="ooo_row">
<xsl:element name="Artikel">
  <xsl:element name="Text">
        <xsl:copy-of select="Artikelnummer"/> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="Details"/> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="Abmessungen"/> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="EK"/>
  </xsl:element>

</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import>
    <Artikel>
        <Text>
            <Artikelnummer>C12-34567</Artikelnummer>
            <Details>AAA AAA AAA AAA</Details>
            <Abmessungen/>
            <EK>1234,-</EK>
        </Text>
    </Artikel>
    <Artikel>
        <Text>
            <Artikelnummer>C23-45678</Artikelnummer>
            <Details>BaB BaB BBB BBB</Details>
            <Abmessungen/>
            <EK>2345,-</EK>
        </Text>
    </Artikel>
    <Artikel>
        <Text>
            <Artikelnummer>C34-56789</Artikelnummer>
            <Details>CaC CaC CaC CaC uli</Details>
            <Abmessungen/>
            <EK>3456,-</EK>
        </Text>
    </Artikel>
</Import>
```

There are a few more changes I would like to achieve but I just cant figure it out.

I need another child within the node Artikel named Bild. It should have an href attribute. The value of the attribute should be the value in the node Bildpfad.

The result of this transformation should be

```
<Artikel>
  <Text>
    <Artikelnummer>C34-56789</Artikelnummer>
    <Details>CaC CaC CaC CaC uli</Details>
    <Abmessungen/>
    <EK>3456,-</EK>
  </Text>
  <Bild href="file:///cmyk/C12-34567.PSD"></Bild>
</Artikel>
```

I need to import this XML into Indesign. It seems that the images path needs to be in a href attribute so Indesign accepts the node as an image object.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you all who read my question. I found the answer to it.

I used this xsl to tranform my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method = "xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="ooo_sheet">
<xsl:element name="Import">
<xsl:for-each select="ooo_row">
<xsl:element name="Artikel">
    <xsl:value-of select="Artikelnummer"/>
    <xsl:element name="Bild">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:text>file:///</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Bildpfad"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element> 
  <xsl:element name="Text">
        <xsl:copy-of select="EK"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Details"/> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="Abmessungen"/> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="Artikelnummer"/> 
  </xsl:element>


</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```